# Country highlighting on mouse over

Tags: here-api

Does "Here" maps support country highlighting, something like in the following example: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart_06d031f6a0bf088f1320a975cdefa0e3.frame

Answer (score 1):

There is no library support for Choropleth maps (which is what I think you are after), but it is possible to create one using jQuery + HERE Maps if you have access to a KML file holding the boundaries of the countries or regions you need.

**Updated WKT solution now available**

Access to KML shapes is no longer required, since the [Geocoder API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder) now offers an `IncludeShapes` attribute which returns the shape of a country in WKT format. A WKT parser can be found [here](https://github.com/heremaps/examples/blob/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/wkt-parser/libs/wkt-parser.js).
A simple [WKT choropleth example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#wkt-parser__load-wkt-choropleth) can be found here.

**KML Solution**

**Hint:** try something like http://geocommons.com/overlays/119819 - Country borders are a political minefield, and this is probably the reason why HERE doesn't do this sort of thing directly.

The problem falls into four parts:

1. Asynchronously **load** but do not **parse** a KML document to read in the "countries of the world"
2. **Manipulate** the KML to remove unwanted countries, alter the intensity of colours and so on.
3. Taking the `<Document>` element only call `nokia.maps.kml.Manager.parse()` to transfrom your modified KML into `mapObjects` and place them on the map.
4. By default the KML will display an `Infobubble` when a `<PlaceMark>` is clicked, an additional listener is required if you want to get the `Infobubble`  to display on hover as in the example you linked to.

Here is an example screenshot, it just highlights countries beginning with "A" or "B" but you should get the idea:

[image]

The code is as follows (use your own [app id and token](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_Obtain_Your_Own_Nokia_appID_and_Token)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>KML Country color test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:800px" id="mapContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" id="exampleJsSource">

nokia.Settings.set( "appId", "YOUR APP ID"); 
nokia.Settings.set( "authenticationToken", "YOUR TOKEN");

// Get the DOM node to which we will append the map
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
var infoBubbles = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();

// Create a map inside the map container DOM node
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoomLevel: 3,
    components: [
        // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(),
        infoBubbles
    ]
});

map.addListener("mouseover", function (evt) {
    var coord = map.pixelToGeo(evt.targetX, evt.targetY);
    var objects = map.getObjectsAt( evt.targetX, evt.targetY) ;
    for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
        var object=objects[i];
        if(object instanceof nokia.maps.map.Polygon ){
            object.dispatch( new nokia.maps.dom.Event({type: "click", target: object}));
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();         
        }
    }
});



var kml = new nokia.maps.kml.Manager();
var resultSet;
var container = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
var doc;

// We define a callback function for parsing kml file,
// and then push the parsing result to map display
var onParsed = function (kmlManager) {
    //console.debug("onParsed");
    var
        boundingBox;

    // KML file was successfully loaded
    if (kmlManager.state == "finished") {

            // KML file was successfully parsed
            resultSet = new nokia.maps.kml.component.KMLResultSet( kmlManager.kmlDocument, map);

            // Add the container to the map's object collection so it will be rendered onto the map.
            map.objects.add(container = resultSet.create());

    }
};
// Add an observer to kml manager
kml.addObserver("state", onParsed);



function err (){
        alert("An Error has occurred.");
}

function parseXml(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("Placemark").each(function(){
        var countryName = $(this).children("name").text();

        /*  YOU CAN MANIPULATE STUFF HERE.

            var newName = document.createElement('name');
        newName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Additional Text" ));

        var newDesc  = document.createElement('description');
        newDesc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(countryName));

        $(this).children("name").replaceWith(newName);
        $(this).children("description").replaceWith(newDesc);*/

        if (countryName.indexOf("A")!= 0 &&  countryName.indexOf("B")!= 0 ){
            $(this).remove();
        }

    });

    doc =  xml.getElementsByTagName('Document')[0];
    kml.parse( doc);    
}

// doc-simple-limited is my KML file of country borders.
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../doc-simple-limited.kml" ,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml,
              error : err
  });

</script>
<body>
</html>
```